# Changing Facebook URL from inside the canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I am building a one page Facebook Canvas App using the JS SDK.

Navigation inside the app does not require a new full HTTP request, so I wonder how can I change the "main" facebook URL (http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/[URL]).

All I've been able to do to change the browser URL is call

```
parent.location.href = 'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/[SOME_URL]'
```

but this of course reloads the entire page, and it's not exactly what I want to do. I see lots of unanswered questions about this, is there a JS SDK trick or something like that, since all history/location access from inside the app frame is prohibited for security, or it's just something we'll never be able to do?

Comment: The solution you already have is all that is possible at this moment. Everything else would require Facebook to explicitly provide a function that can communicate with the parent window and have it change its location itself using the HTML5 History API. But what for? Use cases for this are so rare, I think, that there is no reason for them to implement something like that. (Plus only changing the address bar is seldom what you want to do, normally you change content in the current document according to the new address as well.)

Comment: There's an entire category of web apps being built right now as single page apps that use the HTML5 history APIs to change the URL to reflect some change in the app state after some user action. So I can have a list of items and clicking an item it's immediately opened and the URL changes, so people can share the apps.facebook.com/my_app/X URL directly. I guess an API call such as the one you mentioned would be very welcome.

Comment: This way is not possible in Chrome:
`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://apps.facebook.com/sampleapp/ from frame with URL http://local.sampleapp.pl/. The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.`

Comment: @CBroe There are countless of use cases for this.